# selenium web driver not able to visit youtube url

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to open a youtube `url` using python-selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

It is opening a chrome window instance and hitting youtube url, but then going to error page saying

> The site cant be reached.

In **this** chrome instance, youtube is not working.

If I put other `url` instead of youtube, say google or wikipedia, it will visit those urls successfully.

By the way, youtube is not blocked in my network. I tried visiting youtube manually in other chrome instance separately - it works fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Dunno whether this info helps but it works for me.

Comment: @BillBell which info ? the code i tried ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Your code works for me. It shows and stays in Youtube home page as anonymous user - MacOS + Python 2.7 + selenium 3.4.3 + chromedriver 2.31 + Chrome 59. Perhaps you have a Chrome extension that makes a joke. Perhaps deactivating those extensions could help.

Comment: The fact that I told it works for me.

Comment: Maybe the vice-versa "youtube blocked your IP when you use WebDriver"

Comment: Make sure that all drivers and Selenium libs are up to date along with the browser.

Comment: surprisingly, the same code is working today. Idk.

Answer (score -2):

Actually it is due to slow internet connection .

Comment: Please provide more substance to your answer. According to the question, other sites are working fine and it is an issue with that particular chrome instance. Internet connection issues seem like a red herring.

Comment: YouTube needs more uploading speed  then others static sites. Today I encountered this problem.i was using 3g first when I turn on the 4g connection all was good.